# Limiting access to a link in Bitly

Tags: bit.ly

I created a link for a test so my students could record their answers on an answer sheet. It was easier than giving them the full URL to the answer sheet. Now that they have taken the test I don't want anybody other students to access the answer sheet. The problem is I can't delete the link or disable it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise similar, but not quite the same, as the question here is not if the user can delete the bit.ly link (he/she states that it can’t be done), but how can he/she fix the problem.

Comment: Both ask about deleting bit.ly links, but the answer in both is that they can't, so it's a duplicate. Want vs how is the same thing when the premise and solution are the same ends @ale

Answer (score 1):

Bit.ly links are permanent — you can’t delete them and you can’t restrict access to them.

I think your best option is to move the sheet (make a copy of it and then delete it), so that bit.ly link points to a non existent URL.